# ROR Form Class with its validation

Tags: ruby, symfony1

I am new to ROR, I am curious how ROR will handle and validate form inputs without extending ActiveRecords. It would be something that similar [sfForm](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfForm) in Symfony (PHP framework).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly feel that you have to read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

No extending of "ActiveRecords" needed ;)